# Understanding two file processing in awk

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to understand how two file processing works. So here created an example. 
file1.txt

```
zzz pq Fruit Apple 10
zzz rs Fruit Car 50
zzz tu Study Book 60
```

file2.txt

```
aa bb Book 100
cc dd  Car 200
hj kl XYZ 500
ee ff Apple 300
ff gh ABC 400
```

I want to compare 4th column of `file1` to 3rd column of `file2`, if matched then print the 3rd,4th,5th column of `file1` followed by 3rd, 4th column of `file2` with sum of 5th column of file1 and 4th column of file2.

Expected Output:

```
Fruit Apple 10 300 310
Fruit Car 50 200 250
Study Book 60 100 160
```

Here what I have tried:

```
awk ' FNR==NR{ a[$4]=$5;next} ( $3 in a){ print $3, a[$4],$4}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Code output;

```
Book  100
Car  200
Apple  300
```

I am facing problem in printing `file1` column and how to store the `other column of file1 in array a`. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]=$3 OFS $4 OFS $5;b[$4]=$NF;next} ($3 in a){print a[$3],$NF,b[$3]+$NF}' file1.txt  file2.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Study Book 60 100 160
Fruit Car 50 200 250
Fruit Apple 10 300 310
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program here.
FNR==NR{                           ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file named file1.txt is being read.
  a[$4]=$3 OFS $4 OFS $5           ##Creating an array named a whose index is $4 and value is 3rd, 4th and 5th fields along with spaces(By default OFS value will be space for awk).
  b[$4]=$NF                        ##Creating an array named b whose index is $4 and value if $NF(last field of current line).
  next                             ##next keyword will skip all further lines from here.
}
($3 in a){                         ##Checking if 3rd field of current line(from file2.txt) is present in array a then do following.
  print a[$3],$NF,b[$3]+$NF        ##Printing array a whose index is $3, last column value of current line and then SUM of array b with index $3 and last column value here.
}
' file1.txt  file2.txt             ##Mentioning Input_file names file1.txt and file2.txt
```

Comment: Can you please explain the above code ,mainly array b and use of $NF is used w.r.t output

Comment: @Arya. I already added full explanation of my code(BTW `$NF` means last field's value and array b is having value which should be added with value of this last field of file2), kindly check it once and let me know?